# Angular: pros and cons of subscribe and async

Tags: angular, rxjs

In Angular what are the pros and cons of subscribe and async ?

For example with the following code:

```js
// async version

@Component({
    providers: [NameService],
    template: `{{ name$ | async }}`
})
export class ZonesDistributionCreationComponent {
    public readonly name$: Observable<string>;

    constructor(nameService: NameService) {
        this.name$ = nameService.getName();
    }
}
```

```js
// subscribe version

@Component({
    providers: [NameService],
    template: `{{ name }}`
})
export class ZonesDistributionCreationComponent implements OnDestroy {
    private readonly subscription: Subscription;
    public name: string;

    constructor(nameService: NameService) {
        this.subscription = nameService.getName().subscribe((name) => {
            this.name = name;
        });
    }

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

I find `| async` simpler but most tutorial that I read about it uses subscribe

Comment: if you need to alter/ use the data in your component you use subscribe. If you only need it in the template the async pipe is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Async** pros : unsubscribe for you, and works with the onPush detection strategy.
cons :

- you might have to subscribe multiple times if you need the value at different place in the template. Even if it is often solvable by using : `name$ | async as name`.
- Value not accessible in the ts/js file (you have to pass it though a method in the template).

**Subscribe** basically the opposite... You have to unsubscribe & it is not  working directly with onpush strategy ( you have to use detecthChanges/markForCheck in your subscribe). But the value is accessible everywhere and zou don't need to deal with multiple subscriptions in the template.

So no perfect solution, but i would say that you have to choose it according to the component and its constraints.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what tutorials did you use but it is definitely recommended to use `async` pipe and avoid using `subscribe` as most as you can.

there are plenty of pipe operators that you can use to manipulate the data in its way, such as: `map`, `tap`, `switchMap`, `filter`, `forkJoin`, and much more.

here are a few benefits of using `async pipe`

- forget to subscribe it's a problem that you don't need to handle if you are using `async pipe`
- synchronous code flow.
- performances - you don't need to `subscribe` few times if you need it more the once.